# Why is a parameter in a dynamically written LINQ operation causing error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to add a dynamic number of Join operations to a LINQ expression. The number is the size of the `DemHeaderIDs` array. The Joins include a `Where` clause with a parameter taken from the `DemoHeaderIDs` array. Using `DemoHeaderIDs[0]` in the first set works fine.  But when trying to use a `DemoHeaderID[i]` in a loop I get the error message below.

When I use a hard coded integer instead of `DemoHeadersID[i]`, the code runs fine and the result is correct.

My Code:

```
private void DoSomething(int[] DemoHeaderIDs, OVContext _context)
{   //first set of joins
    var q = from oh in _context.OrgHierarchy
            join odd in _context.OrgDemoData on oh.Identifier equals odd.Identifier
            join dh in _context.DemoHeader.Where(h => h.DemoHeaderId == DemoHeaderIDs[0]) on odd.Demoheaderid equals dh.DemoHeaderId
            select new
            {
                Name = odd.Demovalue,
                Parent = "All",
                Identifier = oh.Identifier
            };

    for (int i = 1; i < DemoHeaderIDs.Count(); i += 1)
    {   //dynamic joins
        q = from qObj in q
            join odd in _context.OrgDemoData on qObj.Identifier equals odd.Identifier
            join dh in _context.DemoHeader.Where(h => h.DemoHeaderId == DemoHeaderIDs[i]) on odd.Demoheaderid equals dh.DemoHeaderId
            select new
            {
                Name = odd.Demovalue,
                Parent = qObj.Name,
                Identifier = qObj.Identifier
            };
    }

    var ql = q.ToList();
```

The Error Message:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.    at lambda_method(Closure )    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.Evaluate(Expression
>   expression, String& parameterName)

Adding `EnableSensitiveDataLogging()` to the DbContext configuration did not add information to the message.

I'm using EntityFramework.Core 2.2.

Comment: The key is the word "Closure" inside the error message. Check SO for `for` loop close over variable issue. Shortly, inside the body introduce new variable `int index = i;` and use it instead of `i` in query/lambda expressions.

Comment: this is the classic "I've captured the loop variable" problem...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Well that did indeed do the trick:

Added `int Index=i;`

and then replaced `DemoHeadersID[i]` with `DemoHeadersID[index]`

You live and learn.